# Displaying JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Trying to displaying individual elements of staff variable in javascript displays undefined in console

```
<script>
var staff = {"stdinfo" :{"si": "HH01", "sn":"DAVE BAN", "sc":"HGT 1 ", "scid":"44"},"stdinfo1" :{"si": "HH16", "sn":"DEOR ORIE MAR", "sc":"JHT 3", "scid":"31"}};
</script>
```

`console.log(staff.stdinfo0.si)` displays undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code gets a syntax error. Fix that first.

Comment: Is stdinfo0 a typo in your question?

Comment: It is a typo. Thank you Andrew

Comment: [That's not JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusing stdinfo with stdinfo0, It's missing the curly brackets, and it has an extra `"`.

```
var staff = {
  "stdinfo0": {"si": "HH01", "sn":"DAVE BAN", "sc":"HGT 1 ", "scid":"44"},
  "stdinfo1": {"si": "HH16", "sn":"DEOR ORIE MAR", "sc":"JHT 3", "scid":"31"}
};
```

Comment: And this has a syntax error too.

Comment: There's an extra quotation mark at the end

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Arye Eidelman! I realized my json_encode() in PHP was deformed